# JavaFX. Проброс параметров args

Tags: javafx, fxml

Столкнулся с проблемой - не могу пробросить параметры из `start` метода в 
метод `initialize` класса `Controller`.
Полагаю, что ошибка где-то в объявлении лоадера, но никак не пойму в чем она заключается. Обозначу сразу, что использую FXML файл для работы с формой.
И так, мой код с моими потугами. Класс Main (стартовый):

```
package Prod;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class Main extends Application {
    public  static Stage primaryStage;
    public  static List<String> paramsList;
    public  static String[] args_ar;

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainF.fxml"));
        final Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        final Prod.Controller controller = loader.<Prod.Controller>getController();


        this.primaryStage = stage;
        controller.setMainApp(this);

//        paramsList = getParameters().getUnnamed();
//        System.out.println("Main:"+parameters );
// Пробовал тут вариант установки параметров.См коммент

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle("MyTestTitle");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("584782.png")));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        args_ar = args;
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

И класс `Controller` (обрезан для упрощения вопроса):

```
public class Controller {
 private File selectedFile;
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

//    if (Main.paramsList.size()>0){
//        System.out.println("Parameter run: file_path=" + //Main.paramsList.get(0));
//    }


        if (Main.args_ar.length>0){ 
            System.out.println("Parameter run: file_path=" + Main.args_ar[0]);
            selectedFile = new File(Main.args_ar[0]);
            connect_create();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Parameter run: nothing!");
        }
    }
    private void connect_create()
    {
        readerObj.connectToMDB(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Main.primaryStage.setTitle(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Собственно теперь сам вопрос:
для передачи параметров рекомендуется использовать метод `getParameters`.
Проверяя его, я понял, что метод `initialize` класса Controller отрабатывает раньше, чем метод `start`, в котором доступен метод `getParameters`. Соответственно, обращаясь к `Main.paramsList.size()` ловлю ошибку `NullPointerException`, логично, но непонятно как это должно работать.

Второй вариант: установил в main методе в глобальную переменную `args_ar` содержимое массива `args`. Таким образом, я могу вычитать в контроллере параметры, однако, чтобы, например, установить заголовок окна, равный имени файла (в моем случае это и есть параметр), мне опять же нужно обратиться к главному классу и дернуть оттуда переменную, экземпляра класса которого в момент выполнения метода `initialize` еще нет.

Соответственно, я думаю что либо я неверно построил всю эту взаимосвязь Main-Controller, либо обращение к ним нужно делать не в инициализации, а в каком-то другом методе.

Направьте, меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: метод start вызывается первым при запуске программы. А initialize когда вы хотите отобразить какой-то fxml файл у которого есть свой контроллер.

Comment: Другое дело что `initialize` срабатывает раньше чем вы сделаете `controller.setMainApp(this);`

Comment: P.S. почитайте про Java Code Conventions ибо названия переменных `args_ar` и название метода `connect_create` не подходят никакие конвеншены.

Comment: Про имена я вас понял. Это тестовый код, написал для примера.  Подскажите как быть с главным вопросом - инициализацией?

Comment: перенесите `paramsList = getParameters().getUnnamed();` перед `final FXMLLoader loader...`

Comment: большое спасибо) мне даже стыдно стало за свой вопрос) стоило подумать в другую сторону...

Comment: Похоже, что проблема решена? Дополнительно, `final` в локальных переменных не очень смотрится` Все поля и методы с аннотацией `@FXML` могут быть приватными. Нет смысле делать инициализацию публичной, никто кроме FXMLLoader ее не вызывает, а ему фиолетово на модификатор доступа.

Comment: @Maxim, да, проблема решена. За замечание по поводу модификаторов доступа, благодарю. Но пока я как слон в посудной лавке, не могу избавиться от моветона в коде ))